# Unable to set an SNMP value

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm grabbing SNMP values for some Ricoh printers, but they have different names for their trays. I want to use `snmpset` to make the names the same, but I don't seem to be able to.

```
C:\Users\Emilio>snmpget -v1 -c admin xxx.xx.xxx.xxx .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.13.1.1
SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.8.2.1.13.1.1 = STRING: "Tray 1"

C:\Users\Emilio>snmpset -v1 -c admin xxx.xx.xxx.xxx .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.13.1.1 s "test"
Error in packet.
Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
Failed object: SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.8.2.1.13.1.1
```

The admin community is set to read/write. I'm not sure if some SNMP values can't be set or not, but I haven't figured out a way to tell.

I also tried using 'x' as the variable, and it runs without giving me an error, but it also doesn't seem to actually set anything.

```
 C:\Users\Emilio>snmpset -v1 -c admin xxx.xx.xxx.xxx .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.13.1.1 x "test"
.1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.13.1.1:  (test)

C:\Users\Emilio>snmpget -v1 -c admin xxx.xx.xxx.xxx .1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.13.1.1
 SNMPv2-SMI::mib-2.43.8.2.1.13.1.1 = STRING: "Tray 1"
```

Can this snmp value be set? Or is it locked somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you would look at the MIB to find out what each object means. I'm going to assume that you're looking at [`prtInputName`](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1.13), a column in a table with [two indexes](http://oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.43.8.2.1) (that's your `1.1`).

Clearly this table cell exists, because your *Get* succeeds. And the MIB says it's `readWrite`. The fact that your *Set* gives you a *noSuchName* then a success just by changing the type suggests that the Ricoh device's SNMP agent isn't terribly compliant to SNMP (and/or has a bug), though unfortunately that's not wildly unusual.

Either way it seems clear from your results that, for whatever reason, this field is not writeable on that device, or the community string you're using does not provide sufficient access to change it.

**For further information on how to use the device's SNMP interface you should *ask the vendor*.**

I wouldn't hold my breath, though: what's the point in naming a tray if all the names can be the same? It seems highly likely to me that these names are built-in and cannot be altered, even if the MIB provides for more lenient devices. This should be a good thing, so if it's confusing your program then you may wish to re-architect it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did change my program to allow for the different names, but I was curious as to why my snmpset wasn't working when I thought it should.  Makes sense though that the tray names can't be altered.

Comment: @EmilioGarcia Again really you need to be talking to Ricoh about this not us

Comment: Just realized you were the one who responded to my last Ricoh SNMP question. I did contact Ricoh a few weeks ago to try and get their official MIB file, but so far I haven't received any sort of response.  I've been posting here in hopes that someone else had experience with SNMP values for Ricoh printers, but for now I'm content with my workarounds. Thanks again for taking the time (both times) to respond.